# Error 500 in Odoo - Problems with valuation field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

After update the Products view trying to make privileges for a tab, I can't access to Odoo and I'm getting Error 500. After seeing the log:

```
Error details:
El campo `valuation` no existe

Error de contexto:
Vista `product.product.procurement`
[view_id: 785, xml_id: stock.product_form_view_procurement_button, model: product.product, parent_id: 361]" while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/stock/product_view.xml:215, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_form_view_procurement_button">
            <field name="name">product.product.procurement</field>
            <field name="model">product.product</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//div[@name='buttons']" position="inside">
                   <button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(product_open_quants)d" icon="fa-building-o" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'service')]}" groups="stock.group_locations">
                    <div><field name="qty_available_text"/></div>
                    </button>
                   <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" string="Moves" name="%(act_product_stock_move_open)d" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'service')]}" groups="stock.group_stock_user" icon="fa-arrows-v"/>
                   <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" name="%(product_open_orderpoint)d" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'service')]}" icon="fa-refresh" string="Reordering Rules"/>
                   <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" name="action_view_routes" string="Routes" type="object" icon="fa-cogs" attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'service')]}"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

How can create that field via postgresql? or change the view product.product.procurement?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to update stock_account module.

Comment: Hello Atul, It does not allow me to update the module becaouse of this error.  ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
El campo `valuation` no existe

Comment: You're not going to solve that problem creating that field via PostgreSQL, because it's missing in the XML view, not in the model or the table.

You should open the file /opt/odoo/addons/stock/product_view.xml, and create the field **valuation** via XML in the form which is giving you an error, if this one doesn't exist yet. If it exists, the problem will be in how you modified the privileges.

Comment: Hello Forvas,The field does exist, but for some reason does not read that field. Where can I change privileges? I tried in Model product.template but it does not work.